# ls in awscli returns "PRE". Why and how to get rid of it

Tags: amazon-s3, git-bash, aws-cli, ls

Using awscli in git bash, the command

```
aws s3 ls "s3://directory/"
```

returns a list of

```
PRE "filename"
```

This is inconvenient as I need to do further commands on the output and I only need the file/directory names within the given directory.

For instance, it would be nice to be able to do:

```
for dir in $(aws s3 ls s3://directory/) do
 aws s3 ls $dir | grep .json;
done
```

Any suggestions to work around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are able to do that with something like

```
aws s3 ls s3://directory --recursive | awk '{print $4}' | grep .json
```

Comment: Note that this will yield incorrect results for folder names that include spaces or that include ".json".

Answer (score 4):

**What is "PRE"?**

- An [S3 Prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html)

> You can think of prefixes as a way to organize your data in a similar way to directories. However, prefixes are not directories.

**How do I get rid of "PRE" in the output?**

- Use the `aws s3api list-objects-v2` command which supports querying and output formatting instead of the `aws s3 ls` command.

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket <mybucket_name> --prefix <path> --query "Contents[?contains(Key, '.json')].Key"
```

Note that `<bucketname>` here is **just** the name of the bucket. Do not include `s3://` or any additional `/`.

The `--query` parameter is what gives you the powerful output.

For example

- `--query Contents[].Key` would print all of the keys.
- `--query Contents[?contains(Key, '.json')].Key` specifies additional criteria on the Key (the `Key` contains `.json` (e.g. the extension)) and then the final `.Key` tells it what attribute of the json output to return.

Comment: the `s3api list-objects-v2` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just by using the `--recursive` option is enough to get rid of the `PRE` string. In my case still was not good because it will recursively list all subdirectories and files.
More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html)

Answer (score -1):

To list all folders:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bkt --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4- | grep "\/$" | sed 's/\/$//'
```

To list all files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bkt --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4- | grep -v /$
```

To list all .json files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bkt --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4- | grep "\.json$"
```

To list all .json and all .yaml files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bkt --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4- | grep -E "(\.yaml|\.json)$"
```

To list all files *except* .json files:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bkt --recursive | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f4- | grep -v "\.json$"
```