# Awscli returns "PRE", How to get rid of it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I'm trying below:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy    
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli  #also tried it with banst/awscli
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - aws s3 cp <SOURCE> s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/ --recursive
```

and it's giving be PRE folder appended in the results, something like

`upload: <SOURCE>/<Project Name>/<FILE> to s3://<BUCKET_NAME>/<Project Name>/<FILE>`

I'm running this from GitLab, i have two similar projects one is appending this other is not.

My question is similar to this [ls in awscli returns "PRE". Why and how to get rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845181/ls-in-awscli-returns-pre-why-and-how-to-get-rid-of-it)

Comment: What's wrong with the answers given in the question you linked?

Comment: Well it works for the listing of files but not for copying

Comment: Like the answer to the question is predominantly modifying the response